# How to connect to Amazon Neptune using Java?

Tags: java, gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

This is code that uses Java to connect to Amazon Neptune.

When I run `mvn compile exec:exec` to compile the program there is an error:
`gremlinjava/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/App.java:[39,15] error: illegal start of expression` .

Actually I don't know where I am going wrong. So how can I make it work?

Thanks in advance

```
package com.amazonaws;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Cluster;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversal;
import static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteConnection;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.T;

public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Cluster.Builder builder = Cluster.build();
        builder.addContactPoint("xxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com");
        builder.port(8182);
        builder.enableSsl(true);
        builder.keyCertChainFile("SFSRootCAG2.pem");

        Cluster cluster = builder.create();

        GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster));

        // Add a vertex.
        // Note that a Gremlin terminal step, e.g. iterate(), is required to make a request to the remote server.
        // The full list of Gremlin terminal steps is at https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#terminal-steps
        g.addV("Person").property("Name", "Justin").iterate();

        // Add a vertex with a user-supplied ID.
        g.addV("Custom Label").property(T.id, "CustomId1").property("name", "Custom id vertex 1").iterate();
        g.addV("Custom Label").property(T.id, "CustomId2").property("name", "Custom id vertex 2").iterate();

        g.addE("Edge Label").from(g.V("CustomId1")).to(g.V("CustomId2")).iterate();

        // This gets the vertices, only.
        GraphTraversal t = g.V().limit(3).elementMap();

        t.forEachRemaining(
            e ->  System.out.println(t.toList()));

        cluster.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you shared compiles fine, and runs,  for me. I'm not sure what may be going wrong on your system.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code on line 39 in terms of compilation. I can compile the whole file with no issues. When I run it I get a list back with 3 results as expected. You can also change the code as shown below to get three individual results back and it still works fine for me. I wonder if you somehow have an invisible odd character or something like that in your source code file? I used `javac` version `1.8.0_181`

```
GraphTraversal t = g.V().limit(3).elementMap();     
t.forEachRemaining(   
  e ->  System.out.println(e));
```

or just do

```java
GraphTraversal t = g.V().limit(3).elementMap();     
System.out.println(t.toList()));
```

Your entire file compiles cleanly for me.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Maybe i think the problem is pom.xml. I will reinstall javac and java in pom.xml